# Can't unlock Widows 7 domain connected pc

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords, windows-domain, dell-optiplex

My school was giving away old broken Dell Optiplex 745s away, so after working on it for a few days, I got it to work. But when I turned it on, it was still connected to the schools domain. So when I tried to change the password, there was no password to change. I've tried many things, but to no avail.

Comment: there is most likely a local account stored on the computer - have you tried creating a DOS boot (Hirens or RMPrepUSB to name 2) and reset the local account login password?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using two with a USB but both failed to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems strange that a school would give away any system without first wiping the drive.

You need to log in to an administrator account to dis-join from the domain. If a local account exists, you can log in locally with the username **.\[username]** or **[hostname]\[username]**. If you don't have access to the local username & password, you can use a linux boot drive with ntpasswd to view and reset these. http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

After logging in to an admin in windows, dis-join by going to computer properties, Change Settings by doing the following:

> Step 1. Click Start button, then point to Computer.
>
> Step 2. Right-Click Computer, then click Properties.
>
> Step 3. Under the Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings, click
>   Change Settings.
>
> Step 4. Then hit Change, change the Member of Option to Workgroup, hit
>   OK.
>
> Step 5. You will be prompted the administrator’s account, type it.
>
> Step 6. Then restart your computer.

From: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c87f817c-ac07-43b2-892b-066a21ef2569/how-do-i-remove-personal-pc-from-old-business-domain-to-join-windows-7-home-network?forum=w7itpronetworking

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) and make sure you "block quote" quoted material ([Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.